# 2D visual display of clusters using a custom clustering algorithm

Tags: clustering

I have a custom clustering algorithm that uses a custom "distance" metric - essentially, calculating a Pythagorean distance between points in five-dimensional space.

How may I go about plotting these distances in 2D (i.e. what are the choices/steps for doing so), so that I can visually see the clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of methods you could use, such as

- PCA
- ISOMAP
- MDS
- Locally linear embedding

Assuming that with "Pythagorean distance" you actually mean Euclidean distance (but then there is nothing "custom" as the distance already is defined on any dimensionality), I would simply use PCA. The others are more interesting in much higher dimensions and for custom metrics.